# create function error to return any in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, dbeaver

I am trying to create a function to returns a row or many rows for the future in my PostgreSQL , 
for this case, I am using DBeaver to create a function 
and the container base on the *public* when I create a new function in DBeaver, 
my function like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
returns any AS $fortest$
declare
    fortest any;
BEGIN
    select * from into fortest from people where email = "test@email.com"
    return fortest;
END;
$fortest$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when i save it  i got error like this

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "any"
  Position: 50
```

do i write wrong syntax ?

Comment: `any` is not a valid data type.

Comment: what should i use ?

Comment: [Return more than one row of data from PL/pgSQL functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a [Postgres Set Returning Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-srf.html). This should be quite close to what you want:

```
create function test() 
     returns setof people 
     as 'select * from people where email = ''test@email.com'' ;' 
language sql;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/npsvPoyjJYXLhLzBywuGwp/0)**

Given the above function and the following data:

```
| id  | email            | name |
| --- | ---------------- | ---- |
| 1   | test@email.com   | foo  |
| 2   | test@email.com   | bar  |
| 3   | notest@email.com | baz  |
```

This query:

```
SELECT * from test();
```

Returns:

```
| id  | email          | name |
| --- | -------------- | ---- |
| 1   | test@email.com | foo  |
| 2   | test@email.com | bar  |
```

---

Another (and probably more sensible) option would be to use the following function:

```
create function test() 
     returns setof people 
     as 'select * from people;' 
language sql;
```

Following query returns the same results as shown above:

```
SELECT * from test() where email = 'test@email.com';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/npsvPoyjJYXLhLzBywuGwp/1)**

Comment: in joining table, i return `setof people` as well, but it doesn't work